# unable to make prediction on test data set using pyspark ML library

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I am working on a flight ticket price prediction data set using pyspark ML lib, which contains both train and test data sets. I have successfully implemented my model on train data set and predicted the price i.e, the label column, but don't know how to apply the same model on test data set for predicting the price of the ticket.

The following code is for training the model on train data set(containing both features and label column).

```
from pyspark.ml.regression import GBTRegressor

gbt = GBTRegressor(featuresCol="features",labelCol = "Price", maxIter = 10)
gbtModel = gbt.fit(training_data)

predictions_gbt = gbtModel.transform(testing_data)
predictions_gbt.select("features", "Price", "prediction").show()
```

Comment: you're transforming the testing data already. what's your problem?

Comment: I want to transform my testing data (a separate csv file), so that the price (label) column for testing data can be predicted.

Comment: just put that into the `testing_data` variable and your code should work fine

Comment: @mck, Sir thanks, the code worked.